# XSLT: How to use text node twice? Once with Spaces AND again without spaces?

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, text

I use this template to generate a list of internal links to various sections referenced by "id='{title}' in an xHTML-doc.

```
<xsl:template match="folder/folder" mode="folderlist">
    <li>[<a href="#{title}"><xsl:value-of select="title" /></a>]</li>
</xsl:template>
```

It works but of course does not validate, because the content of 'title' may contain sapces and the rule says that an "id" cannot have a space.

Let's assume the content of {title} is: 'Title with spaces'.

What I am trying to achieve is to remove space(s) from the content of {title} to be inserted into the href= only so the result look like this:

```
<a href="Titlewithspaces">
```

and then somehow use the original content of {title} again, so the complete resulting line becomes:

```
<li>[<a href="#Titlewithspaces">Title with spaces</a>]</li>
```

Is this possible at all ? If so, can someone tell me how to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A general solution (both XPath 1.0 and XPath 2.0  -- respectively XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0) when we want to replace any non-alhanumeric character with, lets say, underscore**:

```
<a href="#{translate(., translate(.,$vAlphaNum,''), '_')}">
```

**where the variable `vAlphaNum` is defined to be the string that contains all letters (A-Z and a-z) and all digits (0-9).**

This is the so called "double-translate method", first proposed by @Michael Kay.

Comment: OK, this works for now:
`<xsl:variable name="vAlphaNum">&#x20;&#x9;&#xD;&#xA;0123456789+,</xsl:variable>`
`<li>[<a href="#{translate(title, $vAlphaNum, '')}"><xsl:value-of select="title" /></a>]</li>`

How can I create the variable 'vAlphaNum' with say a Regular Expression reflecting this
matching the pattern: `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9:_.-]` (Meaning only these chars are allowed, all others removed)??

Comment: @snahl: You need just to read and understand my answer. Then apply it for the "tail" of the string, while testing separately the requirements for the starting character of the string. In case you are using XSLT 2.0, read about RegEx in XPath 2.0.

Comment: Finally I understand your answer, an old post of yours: [link](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200203/msg01524.html). And now it works, thanks a lot. Now the last bit. Finally the clean string for may contain numbers, but the beginning char must be an ASCII alpha char `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9:_.-]` . As I am not using XSLT 2.0 is there a way to apply that rule in XSLT 1.0? (or should I formulate that as a new question?)

Comment: @snahl: Use: `contains($vLegal1stChars, substring($vYourString,1,1))` Is my answer useful?

Comment: Yes, your answer was very helpful. You may check the final result here: [link](http://tiny.cc/kpyrd). (pls never mind the current state of data displayed, it will be corrected in the next step). Had a bit of trouble to apply 'contains' because the original template constructed an '<li>' over several iterations until closing with the '</li>'tag at the very end of the template. Apparently the 'choose'-function requires tags to be closed. So I had to double up some code. I must still learn a whole lot. Your tips were really helpful and helped me achieve my goal, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `translate()` function:

```
    translate(title, '&#x20;&#x9;&#xD;&#xA;', '')
```

Applying it to your example template:

```
<xsl:template match="folder/folder" mode="folderlist">
    <li>[<a href="#{translate(title, '&#x20;&#x9;&#xD;&#xA;', '')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="title" /></a>]</li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, your reply helped me to find the function:replace(string,pattern,replace). Which one is more suitable?    Still, would appreciate to find the proper syntax for the complete XSLT code.

Comment: empo and @MadsHansen: I do understand both your suggestions, but I do not know how to get that data into the 'href'-Tag - I am stuck.

Comment: Put it inside the Attribute Value Template, where you are currently referencing the `title`.  I've updated our answers to show how to apply it.

Comment: @snahi, `replace()` is an XPath 2.0 / XSLT 2.0 function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `normalize-space()` function to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace and collapse any repeating whitespace characters into a single one, then use the `translate()` function to replace any remaining spaces with nothing.

```
translate(normalize-space(title),' ',''))
```

Applying it to your example template:

```
<xsl:template match="folder/folder" mode="folderlist">
    <li>[<a href="#{translate(normalize-space(title),' ','')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="title" /></a>]</li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Great this works after removing the closing parenthesis: {translate(normalize-space(title),' ','')}. Next step is to remove special chars like @DimitreNovatchev suggests. Thanks.